# Is there a way to override a repository URL in a downstream Maven dependency from the pom.xml file?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty, pom.xml

I'm coming into a new project that has a downstream dependency on jetty-project version `7.3.0.v20110203`. The pom of this version of jetty-project has a downstream dependency on jetty-parent version 16.

Now the kicker on this one is that pom for jetty-project points the repository URL to:

http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/jetty/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-parent/16/jetty-parent-16.pom

However, this URL does not work since Maven gets a 301 response which it sees and an invalid pom; interesting considering the pom does pop up from the browser:

```html
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The correct URL is now for the Central Repository:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-parent/16/jetty-parent-16.pom

Is there a way that I can make changes to my current project pom to override the URL settings used in the jetty-project pom to point to the new URL?

I've searched a bit online and tried a few obvious approaches, but have not yet been successful. Also, I want to avoid modifying `settings.xml` with a mirror since I would like to keep this in the pom so other developers don't encounter the same pain.

Alternatively, if there is a way to get the old URL to work by making some other pom changes besides overriding, then that answer would work as well.

Comment: Just use an more recent version of the jetty-parent instead of that broken version?

Comment: @khmarbaise Unfortunately the dependency was added indirectly and we did not have direct control over it. Some refactoring removed this and it is not a blocking issue, but I'm still interested if there's a way to handle this in the pom without modifying setting.xml, although I have a feeling it's not possible.

If someone has a definitive answer why this is not possible that would be great and an acceptable answer as well. Where are the Maven gurus to close this one out!?